# Как проверить наличие одного из значений, разделённых разделителем, в поле строки SQL Oracle

Tags: sql

Дано: находим поле (например `select field5 from table1 where id = 123456`) его значение: Q;W;R;T;TY.
Надо: найти в нём значение "T", чистое "T", не наличие "T" вообще, а наличие "T" разделённого ";".
Т.е. например мне надо в селект добавить условие, что есть "T" в поле  `field5`.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test (id INT, txt VARCHAR2(255));
> INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 'Q;W;R;T;TY');
> INSERT INTO test VALUES (2, 'Q;W;R;TT;TY');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT id, txt, INSTR(';' || txt || ';', ';T;') is_present
> FROM test
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | TXT         | IS_PRESENT
> -: | :---------- | ---------:
>  1 | Q;W;R;T;TY  |          7
>  2 | Q;W;R;TT;TY |          0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=de1a991d82882a3354ea1a759eef526f)*

Comment: Круто, спасибо.  Продолжу вопрос: можно ли теперь, получив 0 (я проверяю отсутствие) из этого запроса `SELECT INSTR(';' || txt || ';', ';T;') is_present FROM test where id = 1` , как-то это встроить в условие селекта?

Comment: Т.е. суть проверки была в следующем, если условия корректны, то БД возвращает результат, если нет - ничего не возвращает. Я попробовал сделать нечто: `select * from test where id = 1 and (SELECT INSTR(';' || txt || ';', ';T;') is_present FROM test) = 0 `. Но так ничего не вышло.  Значит смысл этого запроса таков: Проверить что в таблице test есть запись с id = 1 и в поле txt которой нет значения "Т" отделённого разделителями.

Comment: что-то не получается, ругается на relation operator: [вот](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b0fed77dcf8f8f890d4cfd2cff9d4ba5)

Comment: @ДенисКондратов OracleDB - это немножко не MySQL... сравнивайте с нулём. `WHERE .. AND INSTR(';' || txt || ';', ';T;') = 0` либо `WHERE .. AND INSTR(';' || txt || ';', ';T;') > 0`.

Comment: все сделал - работает как надо, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Еще как вариант можно применить [REGEXP_LIKE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Pattern-matching-Conditions.html#GUID-D2124F3A-C6E4-4CCA-A40E-2FFCABFD8E19):

```
with table1 as (
    select 'Q;W;R;T;TY' as field5,
           12345        as id
    from dual
    union
    select 'Q;W;R;TY' as field5,
           12345      as id
    from dual
    union
    select 'Q;W;R;T' as field5,
           12345     as id
    from dual
    union
    select 'T'   as field5,
           12345 as id
    from dual)
select field5
from table1
where id = 12345
  and regexp_like(field5, '(^|;)T(;|$)');
```

Comment: @Akina Спасибо. Внёс изменения

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать использовать следующий синтаксис:

```
SELECT 
  field5 
FROM 
  table1 
WHERE 
  id = 123456 
  AND название_поля_с_искомым_содержимым LIKE 'T;';
```

Оператор `LIKE` используется для сравнения строк. В отличие от операторов отношения равно `=` и не равно `<>`, `LIKE` позволяет сравнивать строки не на полное совпадение (не совпадение), а в соответствии с шаблоном. Шаблон может включать обычные символы и символы-шаблоны. При сравнении с шаблоном, его обычные символы должны в точности совпадать с символами, указанными в строке. Символы-шаблоны могут совпадать с произвольными элементами символьной строки.

| Символ-шаблон | Описание | Пример |
| --- | --- | --- |
| % | Любая строка, содержащая ноль или более символов | `SELECT * FROM book WHERE author LIKE '%М.%'` выполняет поиск и выдает все книги, инициалы авторов которых содержат «М.» |
| _ (подчеркивание) | Любой одиночный символ | `SELECT * FROM book WHERE title LIKE 'Поэм_'` выполняет поиск и выдает все книги, названия которых либо «Поэма», либо «Поэмы» и пр. |

Comment: при таком способе не все значения найдутся, например, `Y;T`, и найдутся лишние, например, `Y;TT;`. Надо добавить `';' || TRIM(BOTH ';' FROM <ПОЛЕ>) || ';'`

Comment: Согласен, уже думал над этим, может быть вообще одно значение 'T'